# Autocomplet() selectable Li

Tags: javascript, php, list, search, autocomplete

it's been 3 days trying to fully understand why i can't make this script function for keyboard navigation.

Search, display and replace are working fine, but when i try to browse the List and press Enter to select one option, it does not.

The Form

```
<form action="/busqueda.php" method="get" autocomplete="off">
   <input name="dataa" class="boxbuscar" type="text" id="despliega" onKeyUp="autocomplet()">
   <input src="/img/btn-buscar.png" type="image" class="lupa">
<ul id="lista"></ul>
```

The PHP

```
<?php
function connect()
{
return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'dbuser', 'dbuserpw', array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));
}
$pdo = connect();
$keyword = '%' . $_POST['keyword'] . '%';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_productos WHERE nombre LIKE (:keyword) ORDER BY nombre ASC LIMIT 0, 15";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, DO ::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$list = $query->fetchAll();
foreach($list as $rs)
{

// put in bold the written text

$reemplazador = str_replace($_POST['keyword'], '<b>' . $_POST['keyword'] . '</b>', $rs['nombre']);

// add new option

echo '<li onclick="set_item(\'' . str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['nombre']) . '\')">' . $reemplazador . '</li>';
}
?>
```

and the JS

```
function autocomplet() {
var min_length = 2; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
var keyword = $('#despliega').val();
if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_refresh.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            keyword: keyword
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#lista').show();
            $('#lista').html(data);
        }
    });
} else {
    $('#lista').hide();
}
}
// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item function set_item(item) {
// change input value
$('#despliega').val(item);
// hide proposition list    
$('#lista').hide();
}
```

Any ideas?

Update:
Short answer: This is a better option [a link](http://www.codexworld.com/autocomplete-textbox-using-jquery-php-mysql/)

Comment: It looks like function set_item(item) is commented out in your JS code. Might that be the reason?

Comment: Also could you please format the code properly with proper indentation, so it would be easier to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keyboard navigation of the list doesn't work out of the box like you want it to. You need to listen to the keyboard events on the list and trigger corresponding actions. Try something along the lines of:

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 38) {
    // Arrow Up is pressed
  }
  if (e.which === 40) {
    // Arrow Down is pressed
  }
  if (e.which === 13) {
    // Enter is pressed
  }
})
```

Then you want to have a variable, let's call it `current` which stores the currently highlighted list item. You will change `current` when arrow up/down is pressed. You'll also have to add some style to the current list item to indicate which one is highlighted to the user. When enter is pressed, you just call `set_item(current)` - passing current list item to `set_item` function.

You also should probably add/remove this listener when the list is shown/hidden, so it doesn't fire on the document when the list is hidden.

Here are the docs for [JQuery keyup event](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/). Also check out a [tutorial on JavaScript keyboard events](http://javascript.info/tutorial/keyboard-events).

That all said, you might be better off not reinventing the wheel and using a ready autocomplete widget. Here is [JQuery UI Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), here is [Awesomplete](https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/) (search for "Ajax example" on the page to see an example implementation with the backend server).

P.S. Here is some advice about your code:

- don't render javascript on the server. The best way to receive the list from the server would be to receive a JSON object listing all the items and then build list out of it. If you have to return HTML, don't put javascript callbacks in it. So just return `<li data-item='1'>One</li>` and then use `$('#list li').on('click', ...` to set the listener for all the items. This way you keep javascript and php as separate as possible
- use English for naming variables, functions, etc. One day you will have show your code to someone and using variable names in spanish will make it very difficult for non-Spanish speakers to read your code
- learn to use indentation. Proper indentation makes it far more easier to read your code and understand what is going on. Here is a [javascript style guide](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp). You can probably find the same thing for PHP as well. There are also online tools that can do it for you try [this one](http://jsbeautifier.org/). I recommend properly styling your code before posting it in a question, so it will be easier for the community to read.

Comment: Thank you. Hmm, i'm afraid what i've got is not a good solution for a search box. I understand what you say. Sorry about my indentation i did the best i could, edited. Can JQuery UI Autocomplete and/or Awesomplete return data from a database? because i saw 2 examples of those interacting with MySQL and this seems to work http://www.codexworld.com/autocomplete-textbox-using-jquery-php-mysql/

Comment: Both of those are a javascript widgets. They live on the frontend and communicate with the server in some way. On Awesomplete page there is an example how to use it with backend server (search for "Ajax example" on the page). You will probably have to tweak the response from your server to make it work.

Comment: JQuery UI Autocomplete is working based on this example, thanks jetpackpony http://www.codexworld.com/autocomplete-textbox-using-jquery-php-mysql/

Comment: @XavierSal could you please upvote and accept my answer if it helped you solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Upvoted but got archived until i get 15 points, Accepted, thanks a lot pony!

Answer (score 0):

enter does not work automatically you have to tie your function to enter key event